# Docker Container MySQL and PHP "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" Permission Woes

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo, docker-compose

I've got a docker container setup running on a machine, which has:

- A PHP Web Server Container
- A MySQL 8.0 Container
- A PHPMyAdmin Container

Here's roughly what my docker-compose.yml file has:

```
version: '3.3'
services:      
  front:
    build:
      context: ./front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: front-end
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: derp

  db:
    container_name: mysql8
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
```

And, for that Front part, here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.3-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN a2enmod rewrite
EXPOSE 80
```

It's nothing too fancy, right? Probably.

Anyway, I'm working on a feature that allows the upload of a .csv file, which will then get loaded into a MySQL table. I'm running into some interesting errors when I attempt to do this, and after **extensive** digging and research, I'm not finding a solid solution.

Basically, when I try to execute this query:

```
try {
  $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $tmpName . "'
        INTO TABLE psy_products_temp_sales
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6) 
        SET
        product_temp_name = @col1,
        product_temp_sku = @col2,
        product_temp_posted_date = @col3,
        product_temp_sales_period = @col4,
        product_temp_qty_sold = @col5,
        product_temp_total_earned = @col6;";
  $sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $sql->execute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $output .= "Error: " . $e;
}
```

My PDO Object is set up like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $charset;
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
];
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $log->error(
    "Could not establish database connection",
    ["message" => $e->getMessage()]);
  throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

Notice the **PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true** flag is set, and in my php.ini, **mysqli.allow_local_infile** is set to **ON.**

So when I attempt to run this, I don't get an error, but MySQL is not reading the uploaded .csv file and loading it into the table. I'm able to actually READ that temporary .csv file directly using **fopen()**, but MySQL refuses to read it. And these .csv files have tens of thousands of rows, so I'm not looping through each row and running a query. No way.

When I attempt to run this in PHPMyAdmin, I get this error:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Then, when I try running that query in the MYSQL container itself in the CLI, I get this error:

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

The only thing that makes sense here is that the **mysql8** container is being denied access to the **front** container's /tmp directory?

If this is the case, **how do I set this up to where permissions are granted?** I'm not the most saavy with CLI or docker container cross communication, but there's got to be a way for this to work.

Sorry this got long-winded. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This needs a MySQL configuration item [local_infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) to be set in a configuration file in the container.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how would you go about doing that, and which container?

Comment: mysql container, [custom mysql configuration](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). Drop in the configuration file. So the custom file will have a section header like `[mysqld]` followed by `local_infile=1`.

Comment: Okay, before I try that, before I posted the original question above I SSH'd into the mysql container and changed the local_infile flag to "on" and it still doesn't work, which I assume is the same thing?

Comment: its not. changes to configuration files after mysql is started have no effect until next restart, but its a non-persistent volume, so there is no effect.

Comment: So I added a my.cnf which contains the configuration to my docker-compose script

I shut down all the containers, rebuilt them with the new cnf, and started them back up.

I did exactly as you mentioned, first line **[mysqld]** and second line **local_infile=1**, and it still fails to read the upload. My guess is that the mysql8 container doesn't have "permission" to access things on the front container.

Comment: that's right. The php gets the protocol message to load the local infile and the php should be feeding it over the protocol to mysql8. strace a test PHP stub would be my guess at trying to diagnose the php side. Also try an upload using a mysql client outside the connection (noting you'll need a command line option for infile).